# Como Controlo una excepción de StreamWriter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Resulta que implemente un método que genera un informe en excel de los registros de un datagrid en windows forms, todo funciona muy bien, y el reporte lo hace muy bien, pero resulta que si genero el informe en excel. y luego lo vuelvo a generar me saca la excepción de la imagen(ya que el archivo en excel ya se encuentra abierto)[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta sería como hago a partir de un IF preguntar esa advertencia para poderlo controlar con un mensaje que le informe al usuario que debe cerrar el archivo abierto para que lo deje generar el reporte

De antemano muchas Gracias,

Comment: No esperes a que se quede ejecutando el metodo terminalo e informa al usuario que hubo un error porque otro proceso esta utilizando el archivo,  libere el archivo y vuelva a intentar generar el reporte.

Comment: cierra el archivo primero y luego ábrelo para leerlo con c# y lo vuelves a cerrar.

Comment: ¿Y si utilizas un MemoryStream para generar el documento en lugar de guardarlo en disco?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías cerrar el streamwriter cuando termines de utilizarlo, no sé si en los requerimientos te pide que tenga siempre el mismo nombre, pero te recomiendo cada vez que cree el archivo tenga un nuevo nombre, de esa forma si tiene el archivo abierto no importará.

Archivo.Dispose();
Archivo.Close();

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo mediante un do While

```
bool pasa = false;
do
{
    try
    {
        //Tu Proceso
        pasa = true;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Primero cierra el doc");

    }
}while(!pasa);
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Gabriel Jeremy, fue la solución.